# Journey Builder/Custom Activity: inArguments data schema

Tags: js, custom-activity, mustache

I am developing my first Custom Activity, and struggling with finding the dataschema with description of an available keys *(a.k.a. mustache-selectors)* for `inArguments` field in the `config.json`

e.g for now I'm playing around with some values like

```
inArguments: [
  {
    contactInfo: "{{Contact.<I don't know>}}",
    eventInfo: "{{Event.<???>}}",
    anyInfo: "{{<???>.<???>}}"
  }
],
```

So my question is:
Where can I find the schemas which describe the entities like `Contact`, `Event`, and other entities available during the execution?

Appreciate for help.

Answer (score 0):

`inArguments` is any static or data bound value configured for the activity.

By default, the config.json file sets these arguments. Or you can add inArguments at configuration time.

So this simply means its upto you to define what you want in there

You can check how to create a config.json [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/custom-activity-config.html).

Or alternatively look at a sample journey builder project works via this github [project](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/sfmc-example-jb-custom-activity/blob/master/modules/discount-redemption-split/config/config-json.js)

There are some [trailhead modules](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/custom-activities-in-journey-builder) to help you understand. I recommend going through them since you are new.

Comment: Thank you, Mohith the link for config.json looks for me like a hidden gem. I passed the basics and even deploy the project from github as my test custom activity, but my problem still actual.

We have data-extention which consist of the data which is mapped manually. And I need to know the shapes of the data objects in javascript somehow. So I can get access to the props I need. So I want to specify proper things in the `inArgumets` field for that so I need to get the Schema somehow. so I can write something like: `inArguments: [{ field: \`{{${dataSchema[fieldId].key}}}\`, ...]`

Comment: @KirylYe It has to be well-defined elements in the schema, I believe. You cannot dynamically set this as far as I can tell.

Comment: currently I found the solution with displaying the fields which comes from the data extention. I'm using non-documented event for this which I found in the legacy private codebases, so it looks unstable i would not post it here.